# What is Check the render method of `WithContext`. Error

Tags: reactjs

I am facing this error.
The error says

```
 got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

```
 throw Error( "Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: " + (type == null ? type : typeof type) + "." + info );
```

However, The component is declared export and defined correctly.

> Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `WithContext`.

```
const ProfileUpdate = (props) => {}


const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    profileUpdate: (user) => dispatch(profileUpdate(user)),
  };
};


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ProfileUpdate);
```

Full version ↓
https://www.dropbox.com/s/yubscdktmeikbqi/ProfileUpdate.js
[image]

Comment: Feels like its because `ProfileUpdate` doesn't actually return a component. e.g. `(props) => {}` Try a fragment or some dummy component to return? `(props) => <div>something</div>`

Comment: I omitted the code.
Full:https://www.dropbox.com/s/yubscdktmeikbqi/ProfileUpdate.js

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Downgrading the version of `react-tag-input` to `6.4.1` helped me (before that, the version was `^6.7.3`).
I found this solution on https://github.com/react-tags/react-tags/issues/573